# Why is the "s" in "island" not pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation

*Island* is pronounced as `'aɪlənd` and I can't help thinking about why the "s" is not pronounced. Is there a special list of words in English where "s" sound is omitted, or is this a special case just for "island"?

Comment: Given that a sufficient answer was produced by quoting Wikipedia, I'm voting to close as general reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Island* was long written with different spellings which didn’t include ‘s’, so it has presumably always been pronounced without /s/. (The derivation is not from Latin *insula* but from various Germanic forms, which also had no ‘s’.)

Answer (score 15):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island), *island* comes from Middle English *iland*. However, the spelling was modified in the 15th century due to an incorrect association with the French loanword *isle*.

For the second part of your question, there *are* other English words where the "s" is also silent:

- isle: /ʌɪl/
- aisle: /ʌɪl/
- viscount: /ˈvʌɪkaʊnt/
- [demesne](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/demesne?q=demesne): /dɪˈmeɪn, dɪˈmiːn/

Comment: Is the pronunciation of *island* pretty close to *ireland*, then?

Comment: @Kris It'd guess so, except the first syllable in *Ireland* sounds longer.

Comment: @Kris If Apple had invented the word, they would probably have spelled it like iLand :-). SCNR

Comment: @Raku: So it would be a trademark and no man could be an iLand anymore?

Comment: @Kris: In (most of) the US, *Ireland* still has the *R* sound in it.

Comment: No /r/ is normally sounded in ‘Ireland’ in British English where it’s pronounced /aɪələnd/. The pronunciation of ‘island’, however, is close: /aɪlənd/.